# Tesseract tesstrain.sh - Error: jpn_vert is not a valid language code

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract, tesstrain

Trying to run tesstrain.sh for jpn_vert

```
tesstrain.sh --fonts_dir ./tesstutorial --lang jpn_vert --linedata_only --save_box_tiff --langdata_dir ./tesstutorial --fontlist 'Font' --tessdata_dir ./tesstutorial --output_dir ./result
```

and I'm getting

```
ERROR: Error: jpn_vert is not a valid language code
```

(when I pass it in as --lang)
I have jpn_vert.traineddata in the tessdata path I'm passing.

I think my error comes from https://github.com/mabhub/tesseract-ocr/blob/master/training/language-specific.sh, there is no case for any vert language.
So as per `language-specific.sh` script when I pass the lang as jpn the script goes on.

Is jpn_vert supposed to be trained as jpn or am I missing something else? (jpn.config loads jpn_vert as a sublanguage but that doesn't sound right when I'm only training jpn_vert)

Comment: Could you use `kor_vert` with `language-specific.sh`?

Comment: Nope, getting the same error. When you run `tesstrain.sh` I'm guessing it checks `language-specific.sh` for valid languages and there are no `_vert` languages there which is why I'm confused as to how one trains it. Is jpn_vert supposed to be a custom language?